# Verify that a manifold is a submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry

**The Problem:**

I know how to determine if a set $S$ of a manifold $M$ is a submanifold. My problem is when we equip this set with a smooth structure and want to determine if $S$ with this smooth structure is a submanifold of $M$.

From the definition we have to verify that:

1. The topology on $S$ is the induced topology
2. The inclusion map is smooth
3. The tangent map of the inclusion is injective

**Example of a problem:**

Using the bijection $\phi:S^{3} \rightarrow SU(2)$ given by $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})\mapsto  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
x_{1}+ix_{2} & -x_{3}+ix_{4} \\
x_{3}+ix_{4} & x_{1}-ix_{2} \end{array} \right)$ we can transport the structure of $S^{3}$ as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ to $SU(2)$.

We then want to show that $SU(2)$ with this manifold structure is a smooth submanifold of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

---

**Question**

> How to handle this situation?
>
> I've seen a solution of the above problem and I'm not quiet sure if I
>   understand the underlying idea. Here they consider $\phi(S^{3})$ as a
>   subset in $\mathbb{R}^{8}$ and show that this subset is a submanifold
>   of $\mathbb{R}^8$. From this they conclude that $SU(2)$ is a
>   submanifold of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})\subset \mathbb{R}^8$.

Comment: In that interpretation, $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^8$. Your $3$ sphere will lie inside a subspace of dimension $4$, hence a submanifold there. Hence, a submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^8$. Morever, sphere being $\det =1$, automatically you will get it inside $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$. Just figure out what that subspace of dimension $4$ is.